# Tabulator and multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am attempting to use tabulator to pull data into a table via a multidimensional array. The ajax URL is:

http://router.project-osrm.org/trip/v1/driving/-70.90916105,42.25582485;-70.8696433396803,42.14069745;-70.932117427602,42.19070835;-70.978133423398,42.2180542;-71.0136192663477,42.27750325;-70.90916105,42.25582485?source=first&destination=last&steps=true

when i try  processing this as an ajaxURL, I get the error:

tabulator.min.js:3 Data Loading Error - Unable to process data due to invalid data type 
Expecting: array 
Received:  object

OK. makes sense as I already know this is a multidimensional array. The first place I went is the tabulator documentation. I found the ajaxResponse callback which *appears* to be the tool I'd need to pull a specific set of data from a multidimensional array like this (in this case the distance numbers located at trips:0:legs:0/1/2/3/4/5/6). I've been at this for days and now I'm no longer sure this can even be done with tabulator's ajax loader. here's my latest sample code:

```
var url = "http://router.project-osrm.org/trip/v1/driving/-70.90916105,42.25582485;-70.8696433396803,42.14069745;-70.932117427602,42.19070835;-70.978133423398,42.2180542;-71.0136192663477,42.27750325;-70.90916105,42.25582485?source=first&destination=last&steps=true";
 var respone = "trips.0.legs.distance";
 var table = new Tabulator("#ex-table", {
  ajaxURL:"_trips.php",
  ajaxResponse:function(url,response){
    return distance
  },
  columns:[
    {title:"test",field:"distance"},
  ],
 });
```

As you can likely see, I have a limited understanding of how to even use the ajaxResponse callback.

**UPDATE:**
Figured it out on my own while waiting for a response. all I had to do was define the array structure in the ajaxResponse callback. Then tabulator knew where to get the data from. Example:

```
 var table = new Tabulator("#ex-table", {
  ajaxURL:"_trips.php",
  // ajaxParams:{trips.legs:"distance"},
  // index:"distance",
  columns:[
    {title:"leg step distance",field:"distance"},
  ],

  ajaxResponse:function(url,params,response){
    return response.trips[0]['legs'];
  },
 });
```

Follow up question: is it possible to pull data from different AJAX sources (say three of them into a single tabulator table?

Comment: To pull Ajax from three separate sources, you would need to do that outside of Tabulator and then pass the array in with the setData function

Comment: So it is possible. I'll have to play with it and make it work